# How to call cygwin in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cygwin, diff

I want to use diff in Windows, so the cygwin is a way.
But I want to call it in the C++.

Is this possible? If yes how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to call diff in C++?

Comment: @doctorlove I want to debug by VS2012.But the codes will run in Linux

Comment: No you don't. You will probably have different bugs in VS and g++ - use gdb for linux bugs not VS2012. Cygwin has nothing to do with this. Don't write bugs. Can you change the question to tell us the actual problem?

Comment: @I use boost, So this is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access a command line utility try looking into system function in C++. It spawns a shell that executes the command line utility in it. So if you have an executable that does the function of diff place it in the system path and the you are done. i think diff.exe comes along with strawberry perl(correct me if i am wrong)